# Using self in instance closure variables

Tags: swift, closures

See below. I understand that the variable closure can be called within any object, therefore self cannot be defined in the context of this closure.

But is it possible to define someFn such that i can use "self"?

```
class A {
  var value:Int = 3
  var someFn:emptyFn = {
    // does not compile, self is not set
    print (self)
  }
}

A().someFn()
```

Comment: dear user who gave a downvote - what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `self` before the initialization of an instance of `A`.

So there is not `self` yet.

If you move the creation fo your closure inside the `init` it will work

```
class A {
    var value:Int = 3
    var someFn : () -> () = { }

    init() {
        someFn = { print(self) }
    }
}

A().someFn() // A
```

> I needed to populate `someFn` with an empty value during the declaration, in order to be able to use `self` inside the `init`. Infact `self` cannot be used (inside the `init`) before all the properties without a default value have been initialized.